# Ansible - How to create dynamic inventory that fetches hosts from microsoft AD

Tags: active-directory, hosts, python3, ldap, ansible

I am using Ubuntu as a control-node, and would like to get the hosts from my domain controller (windows server 2022), the [LDAP-Inventory Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/microsoft/ad/docsite/guide_ldap_inventory.html#ansible-collections-microsoft-ad-docsite-guide-ldap-inventory) & [microsoft.ad.ldap inventory – Inventory plugin for Active Directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/microsoft/ad/ldap_inventory.html#ansible-collections-microsoft-ad-ldap-inventory-requirements) docs aren't helpful enough.

I created a file called `inventory.microsoft.ad.yml` also tried `inventory.microsoft.ad.ldap.yml`, and filled it with the following:

```
plugin: microsoft.ad.ldap
server: ldap://example.domain.com
base_dn: dc=example,dc=com
bind_dn: cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com
bind_password: admin_pass
query_filter: (objectClass=computer)
```

After that, I ran `ansible-inventory -i /etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml --list`

and I got the following error:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml with auto
plugin: inventory config '/etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml' specifies
unknown plugin 'microsoft.ad.ldap'
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml with yaml
plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml with ini
plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed,
this character is reserved to provide a port.
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/inventory.microsoft.ad.yml as an
inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
```

Not sure why it returns `unknown plugin microsoft.ad.ldap` The docs uses this plugin and
I verified that microsoft.ad is installed by running `ansible-galaxy collection list`.

I also made sure to install the requirements specified in the docs:

- dnspython
- pyspnego >= 0.8.0
- pyspnego[kerberos]
- sansldap

I am not even sure that my steps are right, because I couldn't find any source that explains how to create a dynamic inventory for microsoft AD, all I found was related to cloud providers.

I also found on the internet people creating Python scripts for the dynamic inventories although didn't see it on the docs, not sure if it is required to create Python scripts or just using the plugin is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The file name needs to be either microsoft.ad.ldap.yml or microsoft.ad.ldap.yaml.

File should be inside the inventories directory.

inventories/microsoft.ad.ldap.yml

Here's an example if you're using AAP: https://autodotes.com/posts/xnl1o59Sdls9p7vZleBf